# What is the suggested reading order for the Bolo series?

Tags: suggested-order, bolo-universe

I have recently gotten some Bolo series books in pdf format but I can't figure out what is the order to read them. Some of the later ones seem to be missing the pages where this is usually written.
I have tried looking up the authors wiki and [Good reads](http://www.goodreads.com/series/49232-bolo) but I'm still getting confused.

This is the list of books I have:

- Bolo!
- Bolo Brigade
- Bolo Strike
- Bolo Rising
- Cold Steel
- Honor of the Regiment
- The Unconquerable
- Old Guard
- Old Soldiers
- Compleat Bolo
- Last Stand
- Road to Damascus
- The Triumphant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These links at [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Bolo-created-Keith-Laumer/lm/1CFAHPLU52NR3) and [GoodReads](http://www.goodreads.com/series/49232-bolo) show the series order of all the books.

Here is your list of books in order:

- Compleat Bolo (contains **Bolo** and **Rogue Bolo**, books 1 and 2)
- Honor of the Regiment: Bolos 1 (book 4)
- The Unconquerable: Bolos 2 (book 5)
- The Triumphant: Bolos 3 (book 6)
- Last Stand: Bolos 4 (Book 7)
- Old Guard: A Bolos Anthology: Bolos 5 (book 8)
- Cold Steel: Bolos 6 (book 9)

---

- Bolo Brigade (book 10)
- Bolo Rising  (book 11)
- Bolo Strike (book 12)

---

- Road to Damascus (book 13)
- Bolo!  (book 14)
- Old Soldiers (book 15)

---

Looks like you're just missing the 3rd book overall, **The Stars Must Wait**.

Answer (score 2):

Good reads has a list of books in the order they were published, im un familiar with the story themselves but typically its safe to read the books as the author publishes them, even if the author makes prequels or the like after the fact. all of the books are tagged as book 1, 2, 3, and so on after their published date. Its important to note that Compleat Bolo is actually a re-release of books 1-3 apparently. [bolo order](http://www.goodreads.com/series/49232-bolo)